# MS Word document randomly changes document filename from .doc to .tmp

Tags: microsoft-word, filenames

I am experiencing problems when opening some word documents.

The filename will randomly automatically change to the temp file that is created whilst editing the document.

MS Word is not crashing and it doesnt happen for everyone on our network that I know of.

Can anyone shed some light on why it would do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `.tmp` files are created for various reasons when editing a Word doc (see here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/211632 for more info), I believe they are harmless, a good thing in fact (they ensure safety when saving, for example) and should disappear when you stop using the original file - leaving the `.doc` intact (or possibly updated if you edit and save).

If Word is asking you to *save* files as `.tmp` when you've been editing them a while it might be a known issue (especially since you mention networked files). See the following support page for advise on checking if this is the case (and fixing it, if it is) - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912257/en-us

Comment: They seem to be permanently changing the document to the ~wrc???.tmp filename.  Word seems to be working fine (as far as I know) and suddenly the document filename in the title bar changes to the tmp file and the original file has been overwritten.

Comment: Try the advice here, it seems the most relevant I think - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/912257/en-us
I'll update my answer to be more accurate now as well.

Comment: Your second link appears to be broken.